# Matching patterns from a file returns multiple same outputs in bash

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to extract a list of files defined in my `.gitattributes` file in bash.

The `.gitattributes` file looks like this

```
#
# Exclude these files from release archives.
# This will also make them unavailable when using Composer with `--prefer-dist`.
# https://blog.madewithlove.be/post/gitattributes/
#
/.git export-ignore
/.github export-ignore
/bin export-ignore
/wp-content/themes/**/.storybook export-ignore
/wp-content/themes/**/assets export-ignore
/wp-content/themes/**/storybook export-ignore
/wp-content/themes/**/tests export-ignore
/wp-content/themes/**/.editorconfig export-ignore
/wp-content/themes/**/.env.testing export-ignore
/wp-content/themes/**/.eslintignore export-ignore
/wp-content/themes/**/.eslintrc export-ignore
/wp-content/themes/**/.gitignore export-ignore
/wp-content/themes/**/.stylelintrc export-ignore
/wp-content/themes/**/babel.config.js export-ignore
/wp-content/themes/**/composer.json export-ignore
/wp-content/themes/**/composer.lock export-ignore
/wp-content/themes/**/package.json export-ignore
/wp-content/themes/**/package-lock.json export-ignore
/wp-content/themes/**/phpcs.xml.dist export-ignore
/wp-content/themes/**/phpstan.neon export-ignore
/wp-content/themes/**/phpstan.neon.dist export-ignore
/wp-content/themes/**/postcss.config.js export-ignore
/wp-content/themes/**/webpack.config.js export-ignore
/wp-content/themes/**/CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md export-ignore

composer.lock -diff
yarn.lock -diff
package.lock -diff

#
# Auto detect text files and perform LF normalization
# http://davidlaing.com/2012/09/19/customise-your-gitattributes-to-become-a-git-ninja/
#
* text=auto

#
# The above will handle all files NOT found below
#
*.md text
*.php text
*.inc text
```

My bash script is inside the `bin/` folder, and my `.gitattributes` is at the root of the project.

```sh
sh bin/test.sh path
```

The script looks like this

```sh
#!/bin/bash

#$1 - current_path variable (root)
file_list=()

while read -r line; do
  if [[ "$line" =~ (\/wp-content\/themes\/\*\*/) ]]; then
    newline=$(echo "$line" | sed 's/ export-ignore//p' | sed 's/\/wp-content\/themes\/\*\*\///p')
    file_list+=("$newline")
  fi
done <"$1"/.gitattributes

echo "${file_list[@]}"
```

But this will return me multiple duplicated files (four times). When I run this I get

```sh
.storybook
.storybook
.storybook
.storybook assets
assets
assets
assets storybook
storybook
storybook
storybook tests
tests
tests
tests .editorconfig
.editorconfig
.editorconfig
.editorconfig .env.testing
.env.testing
.env.testing
.env.testing .eslintignore
.eslintignore
.eslintignore
.eslintignore .eslintrc
.eslintrc
.eslintrc
.eslintrc .gitignore
.gitignore
.gitignore
.gitignore .stylelintrc
.stylelintrc
.stylelintrc
.stylelintrc babel.config.js
babel.config.js
babel.config.js
babel.config.js composer.json
composer.json
composer.json
composer.json composer.lock
composer.lock
composer.lock
composer.lock package.json
package.json
package.json
package.json package-lock.json
package-lock.json
package-lock.json
package-lock.json phpcs.xml.dist
phpcs.xml.dist
phpcs.xml.dist
phpcs.xml.dist phpstan.neon
phpstan.neon
phpstan.neon
phpstan.neon phpstan.neon.dist
phpstan.neon.dist
phpstan.neon.dist
phpstan.neon.dist postcss.config.js
postcss.config.js
postcss.config.js
postcss.config.js webpack.config.js
webpack.config.js
webpack.config.js
webpack.config.js CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md
CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md
CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md
CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md
```

Expected output:

```sh
.storybook
assets
storybook
tests
.editorconfig
.env.testing
.eslintignore
.eslintrc
.gitignore
.stylelintrc
babel.config.js
composer.json
composer.lock
package.json
package-lock.json
phpcs.xml.dist
phpstan.neon
phpstan.neon.dist
postcss.config.js
webpack.config.js
CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: The same as the above but just with one file, not multiple ones. Thanks for the upvoat. I'll add the expected output 

Comment: Some advice, don't use `sh` to execute a `bash` script or any other script, It's like executing `sh ./my_python_script.py`. On some system `sh` points to something else and not `bash` so expect some unexpected output. Also embedding `sed` inside a `while read` loop is not ideal since `sed` will have to be executed on each line, say you have 1k lines to process then `sed` will have to be executed 1k times as well. Not to mention you're piping `sed` to `sed`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Will fix this. This script should be run on GH actions so I'll see what errors I'll get when I'll test it 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others will likely point out, there are other (simpler, more efficient) ways to do what the OP is looking to do; the objective of this answer is to address the behavior of the OP's current `sed` code.

By default `sed` will pass input through to stdout. Consider:

```
$ line='/wp-content/themes/**/.storybook export-ignore'
$ echo "${line}" | sed 's/ export-ignore//'
/wp-content/themes/**/.storybook
```

By adding the `p` directive to the `sed` command you are telling `sed` to print the result to stdout.  Consider:

```
$ line='/wp-content/themes/**/.storybook export-ignore'
$ echo "${line}" | sed 's/ export-ignore//p'
/wp-content/themes/**/.storybook
/wp-content/themes/**/.storybook
```

As you can see we get 2 sets of output ... one set due to the normal behavior of `sed` ... one set due to the additional `p` directive.

If you want to use the `p` directive and eliminate the 'duplicate' output you can add the `-n` (aka `--quiet`/`--silent`) flag which disables `sed's` default behavior of passing input through to stdout. Consider:

```
$ line='/wp-content/themes/**/.storybook export-ignore'
$ echo "${line}" | sed -n 's/ export-ignore//p'
/wp-content/themes/**/.storybook
```

Because you have 2 `sed` commands using the `p` directive, while **not** using the `-n` flag, you end up with a total of 4 copies of each matching input (the first `sed` generating 2 lines of output; the second `sed` then doubling the output again).

To remove the 'duplicates' there are a couple options:

- remove the `p` directive from both `sed` commands or ...
- add the `-n` flag to both `sed` commands

Comment: Great explanation and that fixed my issue. Totally missed the point of `p`, I don't use bash that often so I just thought that it's a delimiter for `sed` 

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using a simple `awk`:

```sh
awk -F/ 'index($0, "/wp-content/themes/") == 1 {sub(/ .*/, "", $NF); print $NF}' .gitattributes

.storybook
assets
storybook
tests
.editorconfig
.env.testing
.eslintignore
.eslintrc
.gitignore
.stylelintrc
babel.config.js
composer.json
composer.lock
package.json
package-lock.json
phpcs.xml.dist
phpstan.neon
phpstan.neon.dist
postcss.config.js
webpack.config.js
CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md
```

**`awk` Explanation:**

- `-F/`: Use `/` as input field separator
- `index($0, "/wp-content/themes/") == 1`: Line start with `/wp-content/themes/` only
- `sub(/ .*/, "", $NF)`: Remove anything after space in last field
- `print $NF`: Print last field

Comment: Wow, that's an elegant solution! I'll have to read up on awk to understand what it does tho XD

Comment: Have added explanation in answer

Comment: may want to add `/wp-content/themes/**/` to the mix to address the case where `.gitattributes` contains references to other directories (ie, `NF > 2` but user is interested in a specific directory - perhaps fed to `awk` via `-v` ?)

Comment: Good point @markp-fuso, I have modified my answer

Answer (score 2):

The quick fix would be: just pipe the output through sort -u :-)

The root cause is your usage of the modifier 'p' in the `sed` regex. This prints out the extra copies. You can just leave it out [gnu.org](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html)

If you need the results one filename per line, I would make the script

```
while read -r line; do
  if [[ "$line" =~ (\/wp-content\/themes\/\*\*/) ]]; then
    echo "$line" | sed 's/ export-ignore//' | sed 's/\/wp-content\/themes\/\*\*\///'
  fi
done <"$1"/.gitattributes
```

or, even better, with awk

```
< "$1/.gitattributes" awk '
/\/wp-content\/themes\/\*\*\// {
    gsub(/\/wp-content\/themes\/\*\*\//,"");
    gsub(/ export-ignore/,"");
    print $0;
}'
```